# ActiveRecord joins on two models with will_paginate not working to get unique many-to-many relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, will-paginate

In my Rails 4 application I have a many-to-many relationship between Blogs and Categories with a has_many :through => join table.

I'm using the gem will_paginate to paginate pages of blog posts.

However for each page, I'd like to show the unique categories that are related to every single blog post being shown per page. Currently I have a query like:

```
Category.joins(:blogs).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).uniq
```

This works great for the first page, yet for the second when params[:page] == 2, the result is an empty set of categories even though this second page contains blog posts with categories.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

action:

```
  def home
    @categories = Category.joins(:blogs).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).uniq
    @blogs = Blog.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

partial to display categories:

```
<ul class="filter">
        <li><a class="active" href="" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
        <% @categories.each do |category| %>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<%= category.title.downcase unless nil %>"><%= category.title unless nil  %></a></li>
        <% end %>
 </ul>
```

The partial logic is less relevant here compared to the collection of blogs and categories being populated in the action.

Comment: I think you have less than 20 categories used at blogs, isn't it?

Comment: That argument just specifies how many you want per page, and when there aren't 20 left it just returns the remaining for the last page.

Comment: Yes, because I think that your query must work. Did you test it at the console? with page 1 and page 2.

Comment: Yes, many times. It works perfect for page: 1 but not 2

Comment: At the console run this: `Categories.joins(:blogs).size` and `Categories.joins(:blogs).uniq.size`

Comment: It's actually Category.joins, but Category.joins(:blogs).size yields 9, and Category.joins(:blogs).uniq.size yields 5

Comment: Because you are searching by Category, you have not second page, no matter how much blogs you have, for page only count Category.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by that a bit more?

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve the intended behavior?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64100/discussion-between-alejandro-babio-and-adam-bronfin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question: You are trying to show the blogs with its categories without duplication.

Then you can do this way:

`blogs = Blog.includes(:categories).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)`

There no reason for show a category more than 1 time, unless you duplicated the relation, but you must prevent that.

If you do:

```
 @categories = Category.joins(:blogs).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

you got up to 20 records of categories. Each of them, with all its blogs.

You must not do this: `@blogs = Blog.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)`, because you can't paginate with the same `params[:page]` as @categories, and you have the blogs data attached to each category.

With only the @categoríes setted you can do at your view:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= "#{category.name} has #{category.blogs.size} blogs" %>
  <% category.blogs.each do |blog|>
    <%= blog.author %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And you don't need the instance variable @blogs at all.

EDIT: Answer revealed through private chat:

```
categories = []
blogs.each do |b|
   categories.push(*b.categories)
end
categories.uniq
```

Comment: I'm looking to show categories with it's blogs without duplication. So Category.includes(:blogs).paginate(page: 2, per_page 20) didn't work, it still yielded 0 even though the second page does include blogs that have categories

Comment: I basically have a javascript filter, and for each paginated page I print out a list of categories which I want to be the list of unique categories belonging to the result of Blog.paginate(page: 2, per_page: 20), because it works for page: 1, but not page: 2

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the views and partials for the action?

Comment: Ok, please refer above.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports it, one option is to use a subquery. So:

```
Category
  .all
  .select("categories.*, (select count(blogs.id) from blogs where blogs.category_id = categories.id) as number_of_blogs")
  .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```